# Safari does not work (iOS 9.3, iPhone 6s)

Tags: safari, ios

Suddenly Safari won't work on my iPhone 6s. I cannot open links either.

The whole thing freezes.

How do I solve this? I updated to iOS 9.3 a couple of days ago.